# based on picklist value on a custom field populate an error

Tags: picklist

I have two custom ( Account Status & Unqualified-Reason)
pick list under account object. If any one is selecting account status has 'Unqualified' ( picklist value) then they have to select any one value from 'Unqualified-Reason' pick list field.

How should i achieve this requirement.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a [validation rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm).

1. Go to ***Setup > Customize > Accounts > Validation Rules*** and click **New** button new create a new validation rule.
2. Give an appropriate name for the VR.
3. In the **Error Condition Formula** section have below formula(change the field name as per yours).

   `AND( ISPICKVAL( status__c  , "Unqualified") ,ISPICKVAL( Unqualified_Reason__c, ""))`
4. Give a meaningful error message to display to user like "Unqualified reason is mandatory if the Account status is Unqualified"
5. Select the place to show the error message as you prefer and save it.

   That's it.

Comment: Can you tell me why we used 'AND' operator here

Comment: glad to help you. because there are two fields. It's like an `if` condition. `if(status=="unqualified" && reason="")` Read more about validation rules and functions that can be used there

Comment: Sure i will check the alidation rules and functions.

Comment: Remember to mark it as answer if it helped you so that other experts won't waste their time